# Userform Tracker V1.3

Tags: vba, copy-paste, userform

Please help me, the following program gives the error object doesn't support this property or method

I am trying to copy data from one workbook and paste it in another workbook but I tried all my knowledge and ended up with no result.

```
Private Sub cmbsendmail_Click()
'Application.Visible = False
'ThisWorkbook.Save
'Dim copyd As String

Dim mydata As String
Dim mypath As String
Dim tfile As String
Dim wbkwo1 As Workbook
Dim wbkwo2 As Workbook
Dim bname As String
Dim Tdate As Date

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Work\Automated.xlsx"

'data location & range to copy
 bname = "Nagarjun B"
Range("A5").Formula = "=Today()-1"
Tdate = Range("A5").Value
Range("6:6").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria1:="Nagarjun B", visibledropdown:=False
    Cells.Find(What:=Tdate, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
wbkwo1.Close
Range("C10:AH10").ClearContents
Unload UserForm2
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

thank you in advance
Nagarjun B

Comment: Which line is it throwing the error on?

Comment: You said this was a userform? If so, `ActiveCell` could be your problem. From the VBA language reference, ".ActiveCell returns a Range object that represents the active cell in the active window (the window on top) or in the specified window. If the window isn't displaying a worksheet, this property fails."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activecell-property-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error might be in the `AutoFilter` line.

```
Range("A6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria1:="Nagarjun B", visibledropdown:=False
Cells.Find(What:=Tdate, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

First problem is that there is no `, _` to tell VBA to continue the line after `visibledropdwn:=False`.
Second problem is that you need to put `Criteria2:=` in front of `Cells.Find...` to tell VBA to use that `Cells.Find` method as the `Criteria2` parameter.

Comment: the `cells.find` is not part of the autofilter ... it is a case of badly formatted code making it unreadable

Comment: could you please share the correct program - I am unable to figure it out, after doing the changes as per the above its showing the same error.

Comment: Please tell us which line it is throwing the error on. That will help! To do so, click "Debug" when the error is thrown and then press `F8` until the error is thrown again. Take note of which line the code was trying to execute when the error was thrown.